# emacs: cannot click right edge of screen

Tags: emacs, mouseevent, iterm2, terminal.app, emacs25

I have this issue with emacs 24 and also the bleeding edge 25.

Does anybody know a solution?

- if I click on a character on column 0-94, everything works as expected: the point moves to that location.
- if I click on a character on column 95, I get an error:
  xterm-mouse-event: Wrong type argument: wholenump, -29
- if I click on a character on column >95, I get the Help menu

Weirdly, this doesn't occur when I use iterm2 instead of terminal.app

My setup is:
OSX 10.10.5 with terminal.app
Using emacs in terminal mode (not gui)
Tried Emacs 24 and now on Emacs 25.1.50 downloaded from 
http://emacsformacosx.com/emacs-builds/Emacs-2016-03-18_01-41-05-2fbdb1bb4c878f8ae17bd69d1b4ff51c47497e41-universal.dmg

Comment: This sounds like it should be handled via a bug report to the Emacs team, instead of a stackoverflow question.  `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: Before making a bug report, run emacs with -Q and verify you can still reproduce the problem. I will see if I can as I'm on the same platform, but rarely run in terminal and when I do, always use iterm2.  If you cannot reproduce the problem using emacs -Q, then the issue is probably due to a package or config you have installed.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466643/emacs-unicode-xterm-mouse-escape-sequences-and-wide-terminals